# Using adb to set the lockscreen and homescreen of android cellphone (no root)

Tags: android, adb, lockscreen, homescreen

I'm setting up a number of cellphones using adb. I have written a script which pushes the custom lockscreen and homescreen png's to the phone, specifically to the pictures folder and that works fine. I'd like to set the lockscreen and homescreen of the phone using adb if that is possible? How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do, 
Write a simple Android application with a broadcast receiver. Inside the receiver class write the methods to set the homescreen and lockscreen wallpapers. You can receive the paths for lockscreen and homescreen via the broadcast intent in onReceive() method of the receiver. Don't worry about the path for lockscreen and homescreen images. We will shortly pass it via the a broadcast intent  from adb. As you already pushed the images,  you will be having the path for the images.

Now from adb you can send a broadcast intent with a couple of strings for lockscreen and homescreen image path with the following command,

$ adb - s  shell am broadcast - a  -e lockscreen /sdcard/lockscreen.png - e homescreen /sdcard/homescreen.png

You can receive these two parameters inside onReceive via intent.getStringExtra("lockscreen") and intent.getStringExtra("homescreen")

Hope it helps. Sent from my mobile.  Please let me know if something is not clear.

Comment: You sure you tested the command? The `-` everywhere are messed up. -a is used but there is no action. So, what are you broadcasting?

Answer (score 0):

Setting up a broadcast receiver is unnecessary if you are okay with launching the app to set the wallpaper. I think registering the `BroadcastReceiver` would require you to start the app once, anyway.

You can pass a Uri to the JPEG file directly to the intent you use to start the app.

So you can set up a workflow like this.

- Push the wallpaper to the device

`adb push actual/path/to/wallpaper.jpg /sdcard/target-wallpaper.jpg`

- Start the app with an intent data Uri like follows:

`adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n retailerservice.justbuylive.com/.MainActivity -d file:///mnt/sdcard/target-wallpaper.jpg`

The file Uri can be read from the startup via `getIntent()` as normal from within the app.

Install and uninstall app commands are also straightforward:

`adb install app-release.apk`

`adb shell pm uninstall package.yourcompany.com`